# static analysis - how to simply detect assignment statements in C

Tags: c, static-analysis

I want to write a script that verifies there are no assignments of certain global variables. Say I have all my global variables initialized in files specifically for that, and that I don't want to pass these files into my script.

For example, I want to verify there are no assignments in any of my global variables that start with `X_`.

```
int var1 = 5;             // that is fine
int X_global_var1 = 10;  // error
```

How do I detect that without reinventing the wheel? is there an easy way in Python?
It is not simple as it sounds because there might be more cases like `==` and if the variable is a pointer to data then `*X_global_var1 = 2;` is legal too..

For encountering **code comments** for example, I use [Comment Parser](https://pypi.org/project/comment-parser/) python package, with a `C` language flag and it works great. Looking for something similar for assignments.

Comment: I have used clang's AST output (json) for getting all declared functions and types in a `.h` header file. You might want to look into this, as an AST should also contain assignments.

Comment: (The flags I've used are `clang -Xclang -ast-dump=json -fsyntax-only`)

Comment: Most debuggers support write breakpoints. Add one and run your program with as much code coverage as possible. But you shouldn't be using such global variables in the first place, because it is unquestionably bad design in some ~99% of all use-cases.

Comment: What would you do with `int *p = &X_global_var1; *p = 2;` ?

Comment: How about just making these globals `const`?

Comment: None of those two is an assignment

Comment: @Lundin for some embedded single threaded design which I use global variables can be good design

Comment: @NateEldredge you are right. I think in such cases you need a 'brain' like an AST as mentioned here to know where `p` points to.. which makes it more complicated.

Comment: @dbush - that's actually a good idea to strict the initialization files as `consts`, and whenever someone would try to assign something there they will get compilation error and have to fix it

Comment: @Orb: You'll hit the halting problem pretty quickly.  So in order to not miss any, you'd have to flag most every instance where the address of your global is taken.

Comment: @Orb "for some embedded single threaded design which I use global variables can be good design". No, almost never, save for the very special exception of a register map (though it _could_ have internal linkage too if done right). Not to be confused with `static` file scope variables which make perfect sense in the kind of application you describe. But they are not global and do not have external linkage.

Comment: @Lundin it wasn't my question whether it is a good design or not. I am not talking about variables that are global to all modules. They can be used only when a module includes the file where they were initialized. It can be a good design if you use it as input from the user with initial values as default. you don't want the code to change them after initialization. but the user can change them during runtime to set them to different values (modify the variable address on your RAM stack).  This approach is currently used in many real time small (single threaded) projects.

Comment: @JamesRisner the source code to analyze is in C. I am looking for assignment parser for C files. Does not matter in what language it is written. I gave an example of a Python package that does what I need but for comments instead of assignmnents.